# 405 Method Not Allowed : Flask web app login page

Tags: python, forms, authentication, flask

I am trying to create a login page for my flask web app code shown below:

```
# Route for handling the login page logic

@app.route('/logins', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Just render the initial form, to get input
       return (render_template('login.html'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] == 'admin' or request.form['password'] == 'P@55w0rd':
            return redirect(url_for('main'))
        else:
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.' 
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

# Set up the main route
@app.route('/main', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Just render the initial form, to get input
        return(render_template('main.html'))
```

This is my HTML login page code

```
<form id="login" action="/logins" method="POST" class="login100-form validate-form">
    <span class="login100-form-logo">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
    </span>

    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
        Log in
    </span>

    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
        <input class="input100" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value={{request.form.username}}>
        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
        <input class="input100" type="password" id="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" value="{{
            request.form.password }}">
        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
    </div>


    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
            Login
        </button>
    </div>


</form>
{% if error %}
    <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
{% endif %}
```

but after clicking on login button

> 404 Method Not allowed

error is coming. what changes to be done in my code so that it can properly redirect to main.html?

Answer (score 1):

Change 'password' to 'pass' :

```
 if request.form['username'] == 'admin' or request.form['pass'] == 'P@55w0rd':
```